# One site, multiple databases/servers

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using a US AWS region to host a website via Laravel Vapor.  I have some potential European customers and due to regulations I need to have the AWS region that serves the site come out of Europe.  The databases themselves don't need to be in sync so I was thinking of just uploading the code to both regions and having separate databases. In addition, I was planning on using a separate European domain for my European customers. Is this the typical way of addressing this issue?  Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Yes, this is a fairly common solution. Not the only one, but fairly common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to keep the data in europe for regulatory reasons, then separate installs are the standard way to go. Also, it is preferable to use a top level language domain (i.e. en.domain.com and de.domain.com) - because if you do that in the URL that is a redirector / proxy need. Set it properly up with automatic deployment and you are good to go.